# Balance not displaying in wallet

Tags: balances

[image]Hi, if anyone can provide some help with this issue:

I recently downloaded ETH Mist Wallet and am @ 93% synced. My balance that I transferred to my "Main Account" is not displaying in my wallet.

According to Etherscan.io the transaction block was at 3,764,282 whereas my wallet is currently at block 3,863,910. The transaction should be showing up in my wallet by now as I have already downloaded the transaction block. (please see attached)

I am fearful of sending more Ether to my wallet if I am unable to resolve this.

Any thoughts, feedback is appreciated.

---

Also, my wallet seems to not sync 100%.... it will download up to 98% then just load in the chain data. (Any advice here...)

Mahalo in advance.

Comment: If the transaction shows in etherscan, then the ether is there, so there's no worries. Have you tried Parity? I find that wallet to be somewhat easier to use / quicker syncing. Don't know whay "...it will download up to 98% then just load in the chain data..." means. Perhaps if you clarify that, it might help you get an answer.